# how to custom sort array by a specific month key

Tags: php, arrays, date, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am sure this has been answered somewhere before but I couldn't find the answer to this exact case...
I know I can use the usort function, but can't figure out the logic to do what I want eventhough it's relatively simple

I have a dynamic area being generated as such:

```
$details[$pageYear][$pageMonth][] = array(
    "id" => $page['id'],
    "title" => $page['title']
);
```

I want the array `$details` to be eventually sorted descending by year, then by month

the month value is string (january, february, march, etc... and not numeric), which seems to be my main issue (how to sort the month 'strings' by actual order and not letter order)

any help would be greatly appreciated
sorry if this turns out to be a duplicate

Comment: can you use strtotime() to convert the names to numeric values?

Comment: Is your data being retrieved from a database?  If so, the easiest way to arrange the data in the way you describe is by using an ORDER BY modifier in your SQL query.

Comment: [array_multisort](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-multisort.php) can be useful to you.

Comment: it is, but i want to sort the years descending and the months ascending..they're in the same column in the db, i now have all data ascending, but i want to resort the years from newest to oldest
array_multisort is re-indexing the years as 0,1,2 instead of keeping the original value :/

Comment: ok, I eventually used krsort since I already had everything sorted and needed them reversed...don't know why I didn't think of that before, thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you use uasort whit this callback?

```
<?php
function cmp_month_strings($a_string, $b_string)
{
   $a_value = strtotime("{$a_string} 2000");
   $b_value = strtotime("{$b_string} 2000");

    if($a_value == $b_value)
       return 0;
    else if($a_value < $b_value)
       return -1;
    else
       return 1;
}
?>
```

Comment: I was about to offer usort with some kind of months-map as a "compare" method - but your solution is more elegant! (+1)

Comment: I eventually used krsort since I already had everything sorted and needed them reversed...don't know why I didn't think of that before, thanks all!

Comment: if they alredy sorted, i think array_reverse() is faster

Answer (score 0):

To sort by key, you need uksort
Some similar way:

```
uksort($details, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});

foreach ($details as &$year) {
    uksort($year, function($a, $b) {
        $montha = (int) date('m', strtotime("{$a} 1 2000"));
        $monthb = (int) date('m', strtotime("{$b} 1 2000"));
        return ($montha < $monthb) ? -1 : 1;
    });
}
```